# Mysql inner join error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following problem, i[m trying to execute and learn about joins as stipulated in W3schools here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Im trying to use a join to get data from 2 tables. Im using the following query:

```
SELECT rentals.*, cars.tank_capacity, cars.price FROM rentals 
                WHERE mvc_nr = '$mvc' AND active = 'y'
                INNER JOIN cars
                ON cars.mvc_nr = rentals.mvc_nr";
```

both column `mvc_nr` and `active` exists in both tables and values correspond.

The value of `$mvc` = 123456789 in both tables

When I run the query without the WHERE clause I get all the data back and the query executes successfully, but as soon as I add that WHERE clause I get the error

> The error reads: syntax error near 'INNER JOIN cars ON cars.mvc_nr =
>   rentals.mvc_nr'

Any help appreciated

Comment: try this: `SELECT rentals.*, cars.tank_capacity, cars.price FROM rentals 
                
                INNER JOIN cars ON cars.mvc_nr = rentals.mvc_nr
WHERE rental.mvc_nr = '$mvc' AND active = 'y'`

Comment: `INNER JOIN` is adding another table to the table you are selecting `FROM`. The table(s) you are selecting `FROM` should always come before the `WHERE` part of the query or else the query won't know the columns you are referencing in the where clause. So it's `SELECT [columns] FROM [table] JOIN [table2] ON [foreign columns] WHERE [where something is true]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Where` clause needs to added after all the `JOIN's`

```
SELECT rentals.*, cars.tank_capacity, cars.price 
FROM rentals 
INNER JOIN cars
        ON cars.mvc_nr = rentals.mvc_nr
WHERE rentals.mvc_nr = '$mvc' AND rentals.active = 'y'
```

Comment: I have to add `WHERE rentals.mvc_nr ='$mvc' and rentals.active='y'` if I put `WHERE mvc_nr ='$mvc' active = 'y'` I get an error mvc_nr is ambiguous

Comment: Execute my query and check

Comment: I did,when I modified it, it worked - thanks for guiding me in right direction though +1

Comment: Since `mvc_nr` field is common in these two tables so that using it without explicitly referring to it  (e.g `tableName.columnName`) will throw exception like `<column_name> is ambiguous` @Marilee

Comment: @1000111 - Was typing it. Thank you

Comment: Thank you everyone